# Representation theory of $su(2)$ and covariant derivative of $L_2[SU(2)]$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I am reading a book about quantum gravity and I lack a lot of knowledge to understand some basics.

They define the $SU(2)$ covariant derivative $J^i$ such as :

$$ (J^i \Psi )(U)=-i \frac{d}{dt} \Psi(U e^{i \tau_i})$$

Where $\Psi \in L_2[SU(2)]$

But what I don't understand is the link there is with the spin. Because they also call $J^i$ the spin representation (so $\sigma_i$ if we study representation of dimension 2 for example).

So it seems to have a link between $su(2)$ representation and the covariant derivative but I don't get it. Is $J^i \Psi$ just a notation ?

Could you help me to see it ?

I would like explanation "by hand" to understand what is happening because I am not very familiar with all this but I need to understand the philosophy of what we are doing. If you think some extra information not explicitly asked in the question are interesting, I would read it with pleasure !

Comment: Can you please write what book is it?

Comment: Try to ask your question in https://physics.stackexchange.com/